# How to set new window

Tags: android, window

I am thinking, how to set up the new window in Android after pressed button. I have the first window, when I have a few buttons. After pressed one of these buttons (for example on the button for adding new name) I want to show new window, when will be only Edit text for new name...

Any ideas, how is possible to do or where to search inspiration?

Thanks a lot,
Manny

Answer (score 2):

You need to start new activity.

```
    Intent i = new Intent(ActualActivity.this,ActivityB.class);
    String name = "example"
    i.putExtra("NAME", name);
    startActivityForResult(i, ID);//or startActivity,see javadoc for your preferences
```

With "startActivity" or "startActivityForResult" you call the new activity. For that you need to create a "Intent". If you want to send information like a name, or a number or something else you can "putExtra" information like the example.
(Ofc ActivityB must to extend Activity and must be declare in AndroirManifest)

EDIT:
You have a lot of example of how to start new activity in the SDK examples (sdk directory/samples/android X )